# Assignment of structures with pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

Can anyone explain the output of the following piece of code:

```
int main() {
    struct student {
        char *nume;
        char an[5];
    } a, b;

    a.nume = (char*)malloc(20);
    strcpy(a.nume, "Alex Popescu");
    strcpy(a.an, "1996");

    printf("%s %s\n", a.nume, a.an);

    b = a;
    strcpy(b.nume, "Emil Ionescu");
    strcpy(b.an, "1997");

    printf("%s %s\n", b.nume, b.an);

    struct student *pa = &a;

    printf("%s %s\n", pa->nume, (*pa).an);

    free(a.nume);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
 Alex Popescu 1996
 Emil Ionescu 1997
 Emil Ionescu 1996
```

What does **`b = a;`** do? Is `b` pointing to the same address as `a`? And when you change **`b.name`** to **`Emil Ionescu`**, **`a`** is changeing it's value too?

Why is only the name changed but the year remains `1996`?

Comment: `a` and `b` are not pointers, so it seems a bit confused to say that "b is pointing to the same address as a". They are struct variables, each containing two member variables. But if you are asking if the member variables `a.nume` and `b.nume` point to the same address, then yes, they do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does a 'shallow' copy of the struct.

Every member in `a` is copied to every member in `b`. Since a pointer *points* to some memory, in this case both pointers of both structs will point to the same memory. If that memory is changed, then both pointers will *see* that change.

But the array contains it's own memory, so the change of the array in one struct, will only affect that struct.

I think you are confused because you used a struct. There is nothing special about it, it just happens to hold a pointer and an array. You code would be the same if instead of two structs you used two pointers and two arrays and copied them manually. You should try that.