# Returning a struct with a pointer to an array member, return value's pointer doesn't point to its array member

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am writing a lexer init function but when I try to set a char* a = char* b I get a != b???
I tried to track down the problem by taking an objdump of the init function to x86 asm but I am very new to assembly so I could not tell what the code is doing.

I have tried moving the a = b line to outside of the init function and that worked but I would prefer if it could stay inside the init function

Here is the code in C

```
typedef struct {        
        char src[2048], *i; 
        FILE *fp;                       
}lexer_fp;

lexer_fp init_lexer_fp(FILE *fp) 
{                                       
        lexer_fp l;               
        l.fp = fp;                      
        fread(l.src, 1, 2048, fp);      
        l.i = l.src;                    
        return l;                   
}

void decompile(const char* filename)
{
        FILE * fp = fopen(filename, "r");
        lexer_fp lex = init_lexer_fp(fp);

        printf("i, src = %p, %p\n", lex.i, lex.src);

        fclose(fp);
}
```

printf shows that `lex.i` and `lex.src` are pointing to 2 different addresses:

`i, src = 0x7ffe20e51840, 0x7ffe20e520a0`. Is this error just a problem on my machine?

Comment: Welcome! `char* a = char* b` is a syntax error. Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem.

Comment: If you have problem with some code you have written, then please *show* us that code. Please [edit] your question to show us a [mre].

Comment: sry just added it

Comment: Should I add the objdump too?
Currently running on arch linux,

Comment: What line of code is getting the error you're citing?

Comment: printf shows that lex.i and lex.src are pointing to 2 different addresses

Comment: i, src = 0x7ffe20e51840, 0x7ffe20e520a0. Is this error just a problem on my machine?

Comment: `lexer_fp lex` in `decompile()` is a different object than `lexer_fp l;` in `init_lexer_fp()`.  `lex.i` points to the buffer that was part of the now-out-of-scope `l` local, since returning the struct copied all the member by value, including the 2048-byte array.  Without C++ to let you overload the copy-constructor, you can't copy or return a struct and have a pointer to itself be pointing into the new object at a different address.

Comment: If you do the `printf` inside the `init_lexer_fp` function the pointers will be the same. You have two different `lexer_fp` structure objects, each with their own `src` array,

Comment: Generally it's a very bad idea to `return` a large `struct` like that, and better for the caller to provide a pointer to its own `struct`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I just wrote that to say that I was setting a pointer's value to another pointer's value

Comment: But when that `struct` is returned, the original version (which is pointed to) no longer exists.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ohhh ok thanks I undersand it now

Comment: @WeatherVane yeah sadly I didn't know that cause it was printing the correct string

Comment: Closest I could find to a duplicate is [Assignment of structures with pointers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35101856) which explains that assigning a struct like this just copies the pointer value and the array separately, but in that case it's pointing to dynamically allocated storage, not to a local that goes out of scope.  The search terms I came up with are finding a lot of questions about linked list nodes and stuff like that, and people getting the declaration or initialization wrong.  (`site:stackoverflow.com C struct member pointing to itself return by value different address`)

Comment: I edited to make your title more specific and accurate.  I phrased it in a way that hints at the answer, so perhaps it's useful to future readers seeing the title.  I could have said "... **the** array member" instead of "... **its** array member", since "its" draws attention to each struct having its own array member.

Comment: I think the most important misunderstanding is that arrays and pointers are not the same. I recommend reading [chapter 6 of c-faq.com](https://c-faq.com/aryptr).

Answer (score 0):

> Is this error just a problem on my machine?

No, it's a bug in your code.

- `lexer_fp l;` This local object will have an address, lets say 0x1234. Meaning that `src` will also have the address 0x1234. And you assign `i` to point at that address too.
- Then you return the struct by value (really bad idea). What happens then is that the struct variable `lex` in the calling code gets a 1 to 1 copy of all members. The contents of `src` will get copied, the pointers `i` and `fp` will be copied and retain the exact addresses they were pointed at previously.
- However, neither `lex` nor `src` are allocated at address 0x1234. `i` is therefore now pointing into la-la-land and de-referencing it will cause undefined behavior.

The general rule of thumb in C (and C++) is to *never* copy structs by value/ by simple assignment in case they contain pointer members. In C++ you would solve this scenario by implementing a copy constructor that gives the pointer members special care. There is no such thing in C, so the solution in C is to simply not write bugs like this.

Rather, you would pass the struct by reference, which not only solves the problem, but also as a bonus gives a *huge* performance boost. And while at it, implement actual error handling, which is mandatory whenever working with files.

```c
typedef enum
{
  LEX_OK,
  LEX_ERR_READ_FAILED,
  /* ... all errors that may happen in this lib */
} lex_result_t;

lex_result_t lexer_fp_init (lexer_fp* lex, FILE* fp) 
{                                       
  lex.fp = fp;                      

  size_t size_read = fread(lex.src, 1, 2048, fp);      
  if(size_read != 2048)
    return LEX_ERR_READ_FAILED;

  lex.i = lex.src;
  return LEX_OK;
}

...

lex_result_t result;
lexer_fp lex;
result = lexer_fp_init(&lex, fp);
```

---

Unrelated to your problem, using `l` (L) as the name of an identifier is widely recognized as bad practice since it looks like `1` (one) on many fonts. In general we should avoid using mysterious one-letter variable names unless they are meaningful (like for example `i` is the de facto standard for "iterator", `n` for size/number of items etc).